# Duplicate Entries in many to many table when trying to update an object from EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Here are my Two Model Classes Student And Courses

```
public class Student
{
    private readonly IStudentOps _studentOps;

    public Student(IStudentOps studentOps)
    {
        _studentOps = studentOps;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
    }

    public virtual IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public bool Enrol(Student student)
    {
        return _studentOps.EnrolOrUpdate(student);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Course> SeeCourses()
    {
        return _studentOps.SeeCourses();
    }
}


public  class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Interface and service for Student Class

```
public interface IStudentOps
{
    bool EnrolOrUpdate(Student student);
    IEnumerable<Course> SeeCourses();
}


public class StudentOps : IStudentOps
{

    public bool EnrolOrUpdate(Student student)
    {
        using (var context = new StudentContext())
        {
            if (student.Id == 0)
            {
                context.Students.Add(student);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }

            var tempStudent = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == student.Id);

            // ReSharper disable once InvertIf
            if (tempStudent == null) return false;
            context.Students.Attach(tempStudent);
            tempStudent.Id = student.Id;
            tempStudent.Name = student.Name;
            tempStudent.BirthDate = student.BirthDate;
            tempStudent.Courses = student.Courses;
            context.Entry(tempStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Course> SeeCourses()
    {
        return new List<Course>() { new Course() { Name = "Social" }, new Course() { Name = "Science" } };
    }
}
```

the Context class

```
class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentContext() : 
        base("Name=StudentConn")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student> ().HasMany(c=>c.Courses).WithMany(x=>x.Students)
            .Map(
                m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
                    m.MapRightKey("CourseId");
                    m.ToTable("Student_Course");
                });

    }
}
```

Data in the database

Student (Table)    
Id  Name    BirthDate 
21  Pedro   2015-04-16 16:12:49.270 
22  John    2015-04-14 16:12:49.270 
23  Shiv    2015-04-16 16:13:45.240

Course (Table) 
Id  Name 
26  Science  
27  Grography 
28  TestCourse 
29  NULL

Student_Course (Table) 
  StudentId    CourseId 
  23            28    
  23            29

With the code in StudentOps table i am trying to update the Student named Shiv to have course 26 (Science) and 27 (Grography) instead of 28 (TestCourse) and 29(NUll)  (in many to many table) Student_Course. But everytime i do that it inserts duplicate entries in the table instead of updating it. What is the best way to update Student_Course Table from the code? Anyone up for help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to clear the `tempStudent.Courses` collection and re-add the collection from `student.Courses` but you may need to use `student.Courses` to get them from the database first if it ends up duplicating the Course entry.

By the way, `tempStudent` should already be attached to the context just by fetching it and when you change a property it should already be marked as modified. Unless you've turned off the tracking functionality?

Also, you don't need to set its `Id`, you just used it to fetch it.

Comment: Hi Klors. Thank you for the comment.  When i'll try the clearing bit. However shouldnt EF block the code from creating the duplicate entries? or there any flag that i need to set up for this. Also when i set the object as EntityState.Modified. i was assuming it checks each property for the changed state. My apologies as i am not aware of how to check for tracking functionality as i am new to EF CodeFirst

Comment: Clearning the collection did the job. But it added new courses on the table with Null Names

Comment: No, EF will happily create duplicates unless you jump through a few hoops to prevent it. You can use the `student.Courses` collection to get them from the database first before you add them to the `tempStudent`, that way the EF is already tracking them and shouldn't create duplicates.

Comment: yes the idea was to put all the retrieval and update function within one context. thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

to update an entity in a many-to-many relationship is EF , you need to perform the following:

1. Attach the entity to context
2. Make sure that the collection you will change is loaded
3. Make sure are loaded as a tracked entity.
4. Call EF’s `.SaveChanges()` to save the changes.

In your case you should do something like this:

```
public bool EnrolOrUpdate(Student student)
    {
        using (var context = new StudentContext())
        {
            if (student.Id == 0)
            {
                context.Students.Add(student);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }

            var tempStudent = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == student.Id);

            // ReSharper disable once InvertIf
            if (tempStudent == null) return false;
            context.Students.Attach(tempStudent);
            tempStudent.Id = student.Id;
            tempStudent.Name = student.Name;
            tempStudent.BirthDate = student.BirthDate;
            tempStudent.Courses = student.Courses;
            Context.Entry(tempStudent).Collection(p => p.Students).Load();
            context.Entry(tempStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Alundra i tried with the above code but it still creates duplicates. Answer from Klors to clear the collection worked for me. But it creates courses in the table.